# $\mathbb Z$ is integrally closed in $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I understand that an integral domain $D$ is said to be integrally closed in $S$ if whenever an element $s \in S$ can be viewed as a root of a polynomial with coefficients in $D$, it must be in $D$.

However, apparently $\mathbb Z$ is integrally closed in $\mathbb Q$, which I don't get, since surely given any $\frac{a}{b} (a, b \in \mathbb Z$), it is the root of the polynomial $bx - a$, and yet $\frac{a}{b}$ may not be in $\mathbb Z$.

Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: You should re-read the definition of an integral domain being integrally closed. It requires the polynomial to be monic.

Comment: @Xam Why do we want to choose it to be monic?What kind of idea is being represented by integral closure?

Comment: @user399625  That extra requirement allows us to isolate an interesting subring inside a field of fractions. In a number field setting the integral closure of $\Bbb{Z}$ still keeps enough information about divisibility. For example, all the primes "survive" (but are mutilated in various ways) as ideals. Doing it "your way" would not give anyting useful because an argument similar to yours shows that any root of any polynomial with rational coefficients is also a zero of a polynomial with integer coefficients (just multiply out the denominators of the coefficients).

Comment: (cont'd) in a geometric setting taking the integral closure of a coordinate ring usually creates better behaved object sharing the same function field (in the case of curves it leads to a smooth variant, but IIRC that is no longer enough for smoothness in higher dimensions). Anyway, requiring the polynomials to be monic creates a useful concept. The other way doesn't.

Comment: This may or may not be of any significance to your query today, but $b \neq 0$, right?

Comment: @RobertSoupe Yes, $b$ isn't $0$.

Comment: Just checking, before anyone is rude to you about such a minor omission.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The polynomial $\frac{a}{b}$ satisfies is required to be monic, namely the coefficient of the highest degree term has to be $1$.